# Arclength of intersection of cylinder and plane

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, parametrization, arc-length

The question is as follows:

---

Parameterize the intersection of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and the plane $x+y+z = 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and find its arclength.

---

I have come as far as parameterizing each variable as a function of $t$, such that

$$x(t) = \sin(t) \qquad y(t) = \cos(t) \qquad z(t) = 1 - \sin(t) - \cos(t)$$

and have reached the expression

$$\begin{align}
s &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sqrt{(x'(t))^2 + (y'(t))^2 + (z'(t))^2} dt} \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sqrt{2-2\cos(t)\sin(t)}dt}
\end{align}$$

I have no clue as to how to proceed from here. I have just started learning multivariable calculus, so I'm not too familiar with special integral identities. Should I just run it through a calculator and get an approximated value? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The intersection is an ellipse. If you haven't learnt the complete elliptic integrals, you can't solve.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see. I guess I should just approximate it then.

Comment: Or solve in terms of an elliptic function. You don't tell us what course this is.

Comment: @YvesDaoust This question was from a multivariable calculus course. I have not encountered elliptic functions before, so I think I should just leave it in its integral form.

Comment: For info, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference